# how to enable lightning experience for a user created

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created user and assigned a profile to the user. Not sure where to enable the lightning experience to the user.
I cant see the user can log in with lightning experience. how to enable it ?

Comment: [Salesforce SE](https://https://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask questions that are very SF-specific

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "Lightning Experience User" checkbox which you can enable either on Profiles or if you want single people to give it a go you can make a permission set, tick the checkbox and assign manually.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_enable_users.htm&type=5